# Query to show table, even if some fields aren't entered

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I have a query and a table. The table's name is OrderT, while the query's name is SearchQ. The query is there so I can have a subform show the results of a search on a form. Though my query won't show a line on the table if it's missing any data from any of the fields.  For example, if I have the fields CustomerName, OrderNumber, and OrderDueDate and I fill out CustomerName, OrderNumber but leave OrderDueDate empty; the query won't show that it exists so the search can't pick it up.

How would I go about in making the query show all things on the table, even if some fields aren't filled out on them?

SQL of Query:

```
    SELECT OrderT.CustomerName, OrderT.OrderName, OrderT.OrderDesc, OrderT.DateOfPurchase, OrderT.ProjectDueDate, OrderT.EngineerDueDate, OrderT.ProjectComplete, OrderT.CutplanDueDate, OrderT.MaterialSpecs, OrderT.CutplanCode, OrderT.HardwareSpecs, OrderT.HardwareDueDate, OrderT.HardwareComplete, OrderT.PurchaseOrder, OrderT.PurchaseSupplier
FROM OrderT
WHERE (((OrderT.CustomerName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![CustomerName] & "*") AND ((OrderT.OrderName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![OrderName] & "*") AND ((OrderT.OrderDesc) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![OrderDesc] & "*") AND ((OrderT.DateOfPurchase) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![DateOfPurchase] & "*") AND ((OrderT.ProjectDueDate) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![ProjectDueDate] & "*") AND ((OrderT.EngineerDueDate) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![EngineerDueDate] & "*") AND ((OrderT.ProjectComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![ProjectComplete] & "*") AND ((OrderT.CutplanDueDate) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![CutplanDueDate] & "*") AND ((OrderT.MaterialSpecs) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![MaterialSpecs] & "*") AND ((OrderT.CutplanCode) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![CutplanCode] & "*") AND ((OrderT.HardwareSpecs) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![HardwareSpecs] & "*") AND ((OrderT.HardwareDueDate) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![HardwareDueDate] & "*") AND ((OrderT.HardwareComplete) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![HardwareComplete] & "*") AND ((OrderT.PurchaseOrder) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![PurchaseOrder] & "*") AND ((OrderT.PurchaseSupplier) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![PurchaseSupplier] & "*"));
```

Comment: Please show us the query SQL.  I've never heard of anything like that unless there's a join or WHERE clause that excludes records based on a given field.

Comment: Fields' values are not entered in table or on search form?

Comment: Lets say I enter data into my table, OrderT, and leave OrderName out as there isn't an order number for this specific product. The query will not accept that whole line, and act as if it doesn't exist making my subform based off the query not be able to pick up the data either, so when you use the form to search for the data with my search button; it won't find it as it thinks it doesn't exist but it is clearly in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simpler test case and work out the logic there.

```sql
SELECT
    o.CustomerName,
    o.OrderName
FROM OrderT AS o
WHERE
    (
            o.CustomerName Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![CustomerName] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![SearchF]![CustomerName] Is Null
    )
    AND
    (
            o.OrderName Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![OrderName] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![SearchF]![OrderName] Is Null
    );
```

When a value is entered in the `CustomerName` text box, that query will return only rows where the `CustomerName` field includes that text box value.  And when no value is entered in the text box, the query does not exclude any rows based on the `CustomerName` field values.  (I find it easier to keep this straight by giving the text box a different name than the field: `txtCustomerName`; and `CustomerName`.)

Same for `OrderName`.

If this approach is unwieldy or hard to understand, you could use VBA code to construct the `WHERE` clause at run time based on those text boxes which include a value.

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast reply! Much gratitude and I owe you the world. I hope if you need help in the future you get it as fast as you helped me, you deserve it!

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a better way to do this, but it's more of an Intermediate knowledge level (not sure if you're there or not).  You should actually loop through your controls and check each one for NULL values, and you'd end up with a WHERE clause that only has controls that actually have values in them.  The problem above is that when you have a NULL, it's saying

```
((MyField) LIKE "*NULL*")
```

and since it's in an AND statement, it's going to skip that line.  You're going to need something like this:

```
Dim sSQL as String
Dim ctl As Control

sSQL = "SELECT OrderT.CustomerName, OrderT.OrderName, OrderT.OrderDesc, OrderT.DateOfPurchase, OrderT.ProjectDueDate, OrderT.EngineerDueDate, OrderT.ProjectComplete, OrderT.CutplanDueDate, OrderT.MaterialSpecs, OrderT.CutplanCode, OrderT.HardwareSpecs, OrderT.HardwareDueDate, OrderT.HardwareComplete, OrderT.PurchaseOrder, OrderT.PurchaseSupplier
FROM OrderT
WHERE ("
For Each ctl In frm
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox _
            Or ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
            If Len(Trim(ctl.Value)) > 0 Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "((OrderT." & ctl.Name & ") Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchF]![" & ctl.Name & "] & "*") AND "
            End If
        End If
Next ctl

sSQL = Left(sSQL, Len(sSQL)-4)
sSQL = sSQL & ");"

DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
```

Comment: I was in the middle of posting this behemoth when HansUp posted his answer, and his is probably better but I'll leave this here just in case.  You really should limit what fields someone can search on, or make a search form where people can pick 1 or 2 criteria from a drop-down and only search on those criteria.

Comment: I used HansUp's and it works flawlessly. I openly admit I am definitely not at an intermediate knowledge level of SQL, Access, or anything really in Access. Though I know a beginners understanding, and with this is has gotten me to complete 99% of the database I am working on! Thank you for trying, and to boot a quick response. You don't understand how grateful I am for you and  HansUp! Much love.