# MS Access - Using Form Inputs to Filter on Multiple Criteria in a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, filtering

In MS Access, I want to use a Form to drive the multiple filtering criteria for a query. In each of the combo boxes, I added null values for users to leave blank as not all criteria need a specified value

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZQEW.jpg)

Currently, I am able to filter on the first field [Type of Agreement], but cannot get the Sponsor field to work. This prevents me from even trying to filter based on the other fields. As a starting point, this is what I have:

```
SELECT TestInPut.[Type of Agreement], TestInPut.Sponsor, TestInPut.[Proposal Title], TestInPut.Div,  TestInPut.[Award Status], 
FROM TestInPut
WHERE ((TestInput.[Type of Agreement])=Forms!Console!SelectType) Or ((Forms!Console!SelectType) Is Null);
```

I tried the following solution, but my code did not apply if I chose a value in the Sponsor combo box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568169

How can I develop my code properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea for this kind of filter is to convert the Null value in the control to SQL that means no conditions on this field. To do this we use the Nz function and the LIKE keyword.

The WHERE part should read:

```
WHERE TestInput.[Type of Agreement] LIKE Nz("'" & Forms["Console"].SelectType & "'","'*'") AND
      TestInPut.Sponsor LIKE Nz("'" & Forms["Console"].Sponsor & "'","'*'") AND ...
```

and so on for each field you want to filter on. Now, if the combobox is Null, it substitutes `LIKE '*'` which returns everything for that field. If it's populated with a value, it substitutes `LIKE 'Grant'` for example. No wildcards (*, ?) mean it's effectively asking for it to be equal.

EDIT: Sorry a few errors in that. It should be:

```
WHERE TestInput.[Type of Agreement] LIKE Nz([Forms]![Console]![SelectType],"*") AND
          TestInPut.Sponsor LIKE Nz([Forms]![Console]![Sponsor],"*")
```

Comment: Hi John F, I replaced my WHERE part with yours and fixed the formatting as Access gave me a syntax error (missing operator) after trying to run your code.

Comment: Oh OK what was the Syntax error so I can fix it? Did it work?

Comment: Sorry I had to leave my desk and got comment locked. The following is the code I modified to be able to run in Access. But it broke the functionality as I can't even filter based on Type of Agreement value anymore haha..  

    WHERE TestInput.[Type of Agreement] LIKE Nz("'" & [Forms]![Console]![SelectType] & "'","'*'") AND
      TestInPut.[Sponsor] LIKE Nz("'" & [Forms]![Console]![SelectSponsor] & "'","'*'");

I'd appreciate any further insight please!

Comment: I should ask: what are you using to apply the filter to the form's data? Are you using the Filter property or the RowSource property? Also you need the second argument of the Nz function to be "'*'" i.e double quote, single quote, star, single quote, double quote.

Comment: I hope I'm answering your question correctly... Within my Form [Console], I use the RowSource property to grab the existing records from my database table TestInput and I added a Null with a trick I found on Stack. 
"SELECT TestInput.[Type of Agreement] FROM TestInput UNION SELECT Null FROM TestInput GROUP BY TestInput.[Type of Agreement]
ORDER BY TestInput.[Type of Agreement];" 
I can't find Rowsource or Filter property in my query since I've been working on the code in  SQL view.

Comment: Even when I took away the Sponsor portion of your edited code, and it doesn't seem to grab the Type of Agreement value set in the Form anymore

Comment: @Kato OK I have changed the query: see my answer under EDIT. Basically I removed the single quotes and concatenation (i.e "'" and &). ALSO just making sure, when you change the selection in a Combo box you need to requery the data (maybe use the Change event for the Combo box to run the Requery method on the form displaying the data.

Comment: Hi John, your EDIT enabled filtering on Type of Agreement now  but doesn't take the Sponsor input. I'm not entirely sure on what you mean by requerying the data even with a google search... It appears to me that requerying essentially refreshes my data? As for the Change event, since i'm already lost on how to requery the data.. i'm not entirely sure how to set the event up. I don't know if this is allowed or anything, but would it be much easier if I can send you the Access file i'm working with ? (As long as you're still willing to provide guidance haha)

Comment: JUST KIDDING. IT WORKED!! I still don't understand the change event and requery stuff, but I failed to tell you that the Sponsor box is called SelectSponsor, so once I fixed that, I was able to get it to filter properly. I added the next field, Division, and haven't come across any issues!! Thank you so much John for all your help and patience :)