# Filter multiple value/criteria from same field in query using Access form text box

Tags: ms-access

I want to filter a field in my query using multiple criteria in Access form.
For example field `Prime Part` with 2 criteria
Here is my form [image: Form]
I am using method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568169
but my result got nothing when i fill value in text box `[Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part]` and `[Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part3]`  and left other blank.
Here is my query sql

```
SELECT [6M_DEMAND].Region, [6M_DEMAND].Partnumber, [6M_DEMAND].[Part Name], [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Top Most Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Planner Name], [6M_DEMAND].[Part Cost], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 1], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 2], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 3], [6M_DEMAND].[Lob Model], [6M_DEMAND].[Region Age Class], [6M_DEMAND].Rtsdate, [6M_DEMAND].Eopdate, [6M_DEMAND].[Buy Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Return Warranty Iw], [6M_DEMAND].[Iw Yield Percentage], [6M_DEMAND].[Iw Yield Override], [6M_DEMAND].[Return Warranty Oow], [6M_DEMAND].[Oow Yield Percentage], [6M_DEMAND].[Oow Yield Override], [6M_DEMAND].Mpp, [6M_DEMAND].[Mpp(in)/Ccc Client Material Class], [6M_DEMAND].[Apcc Material Class/Ccc Ent Material Class], [6M_DEMAND].Jpn4hr, [6M_DEMAND].[Asu Count], [6M_DEMAND].Hostlocid, [6M_DEMAND].Country, [6M_DEMAND].Ib, [6M_DEMAND].[Stock Level Custom 2/Asl Lock Note], [6M_DEMAND].Aslitem, [6M_DEMAND].Safetystock, [6M_DEMAND].Ohb, [6M_DEMAND].[Fg Ohb (ohgood)], [6M_DEMAND].[Apj - Stock In Transit (csk)], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg 12m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -6m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -5m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -4m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -3m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -2m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -1m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -4w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -3w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -2w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -1w], [6M_DEMAND].[Current Wk Usg], [6M_DEMAND].[Op Qty], [6M_DEMAND].[Planner Code], [6M_DEMAND].[Region Lob], [6M_DEMAND].[Regional Com Code]
FROM 6M_DEMAND
WHERE (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part] Is Null
    )
 AND
    (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part1] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part1] Is Null
    )
 AND
    (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part2] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part2] Is Null
    )
AND
    (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part3] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part3] Is Null
    )
 AND
    (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part4] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part4] Is Null
    )
 AND
    (
           [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part] Like "*" & [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part5] & "*"
        OR [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part5] Is Null
    )
GROUP BY [6M_DEMAND].Region, [6M_DEMAND].Partnumber, [6M_DEMAND].[Part Name], [6M_DEMAND].[Prime Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Top Most Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Planner Name], [6M_DEMAND].[Part Cost], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 1], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 2], [6M_DEMAND].[Gcc 3], [6M_DEMAND].[Lob Model], [6M_DEMAND].[Region Age Class], [6M_DEMAND].Rtsdate, [6M_DEMAND].Eopdate, [6M_DEMAND].[Buy Part], [6M_DEMAND].[Return Warranty Iw], [6M_DEMAND].[Iw Yield Percentage], [6M_DEMAND].[Iw Yield Override], [6M_DEMAND].[Return Warranty Oow], [6M_DEMAND].[Oow Yield Percentage], [6M_DEMAND].[Oow Yield Override], [6M_DEMAND].Mpp, [6M_DEMAND].[Mpp(in)/Ccc Client Material Class], [6M_DEMAND].[Apcc Material Class/Ccc Ent Material Class], [6M_DEMAND].Jpn4hr, [6M_DEMAND].[Asu Count], [6M_DEMAND].Hostlocid, [6M_DEMAND].Country, [6M_DEMAND].Ib, [6M_DEMAND].[Stock Level Custom 2/Asl Lock Note], [6M_DEMAND].Aslitem, [6M_DEMAND].Safetystock, [6M_DEMAND].Ohb, [6M_DEMAND].[Fg Ohb (ohgood)], [6M_DEMAND].[Apj - Stock In Transit (csk)], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg 12m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -6m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -5m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -4m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -3m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -2m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -1m], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -4w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -3w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -2w], [6M_DEMAND].[Usg -1w], [6M_DEMAND].[Current Wk Usg], [6M_DEMAND].[Op Qty], [6M_DEMAND].[Planner Code], [6M_DEMAND].[Region Lob], [6M_DEMAND].[Regional Com Code];
```

Can you help me on this
Thank you.

Comment: The example you followed is different from your situation because your multiple criteria are for same field. The AND operator won't work because no single record can meet the condition of matching ALL inputs. What happens when you use OR instead?

Comment: Why use GROUP BY? There are no aggregate calcs.

Comment: We using OR my query will became to big then cannot export to excel.
I will try the option you provide below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Use InStr() function with concatenated controls:

```
SELECT 6M_Demand.* FROM 6M_Demand
WHERE InStr([Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part1] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part2] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part3] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part4] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part5], [Prime Part]) > 0;
```

2. Use LIKE and wildcard with concatenated controls:

```
SELECT 6M_Demand.* FROM 6M_Demand
WHERE [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part1] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part2] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part3] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part4] & "," 
& [Forms]![6M_DEMAND_FILTER]![Prime Part5] LIKE "*" & [Prime Part] & "*";
```

3. VBA constructs filter criteria and applies to form or report

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Thank you so much  
I do get the general logic that need use `or` but when i do that the query will include all data if any `textbox` left blank.  
With your answer i able to get 2 value even other is left blank.